# Split string with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, exception, linq-to-entities

I want to order by my results with the matches count in my string line.

So here is code

```
.ThenByDescending(p => p.Title.ToLower()
                              .Split(' ')
                              .Count(w => words.Any(w.Contains)));
```

But it bring me error and says that LINQ can't parse `Split` into SQL.

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String[]
>   Split(Char[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a
>   store expression.

How can I implement Split via LINQ?

For example, for this array it must order in this way

```
words = { "a", "ab" }

ab a ggaaag gh //3 matches
ba ab ggt //2 matches
dd //0 matches
```

Answer (score 8):

it means that Linq to entities failed to find translation of split method that can be written as sql query. if you want to perform split functions you have to bring the record in memory by calling `ToList()`, `AsEnumerable()` etc.

```
var result = (from t in db.Table
              select t).AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x=>x.Column).ThenByDescending(p=>p.Title.ToLower.Split(' ')....);
```

Comment: But that will cause loading all the data in memory and performing LINQ to Objects transformation against it, will it not?

Comment: yep that's true. Optimally you can apply conditions in where clause before calling `AsEnumerable`. you can't do it without bringing objects to memory

Comment: I guess it will crash with large tables. I agree with abatishchev.

Comment: As i said you won't always be interested in all data of the table you can filter it first using where clause

Comment: alternately, you can create a view and bring it on your emdx if you are more into performance than patterns.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to perform the sorting in LINQ to Objects because LINQ to Entities cannot translate the C# code into SQL (or the language of whatever DB you're using).

You can do it like this.

```
var results = 
  objectContext
  .Where(a => a == b) //Whatever
  .AsEnumerable()
  .ThenByDescending(p=>p.Title.ToLower().Split(' ').Count(w=>words.Any(w.Contains)));
```

`AsEnumerable()` (along with `ToArray()` or `ToList()`) turn the LINQ to Entities back into LINQ to Objects.

Answer (score 2):

One can't expect LINQ to Entities to be able to convert that to SQL.

The best solution is to change the schema such that each word in a post's title is stored as a separate row in a separate table (with the appropriate associations). The query can then use explicit (group) join operations or the FK association property.

If you can't do this and yet want the query to run on the database, you'll have to look into writing a user-defined function to work with delimited strings. Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql) for more info. This will be a lot of work though.

The easiest solution (if you can afford to do it) of course is to pull everything back to the client just use LINQ to Objects for that part of the query, as mentioned by @Muhammad Adeel Zahid.